# Is there a .NET Control Similar to the Access 2007 Split Form?

Tags: .net, ms-access

Is there a .NET Control Similar to the Access 2007 Split Form?

Or has anyone built such a control?

I upgraded a small personal Name and Address DB to Access 2007 and noticed the Form had a property called “Default View” which can be set to “Split Form”. “Split Form” mode has a GridView and a Form together in one control. When a record is clicked in the GridView, it shows up in the form and it can be edited in either the GridView and/or the Form by setting some properties. Pretty slick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but pretty much all you need is:

- a split container
- a user control containing your actual form
- a grid view

Now you just hook up the grid view's item selection events with a controller that loads data into the user control's child controls.

From what I can tell, there Access Split Form doesn't do a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

A Flex Grid Control will probably do what you want but you will need to write a bit of VBA code, have a look at my Flex Grid Demo program for some examples.

Go to http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=180

HTH

Peter Hibbs.